# How to apply wrapper to this flex box and keep the responsiveness

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to have the elements in the middle 1240px of the screen using a wrapper, however, when I add the wrapper, the `.space` `<li>` element stops shrinking when I shrink down the page making my sign in button and sign out button disappear in the right side of the page. Also I've been wondering whether using an empty `<li>` with flex: 1 is the correct way of creating the space in between the first 3 `<li>` elements and the last 2.

```css
.container {
    display: flex;
}
.container>li {
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1em;
    color: white;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-color: black;
    list-style-type: none;
}
.space {
    flex: 1;
}
.wrapper {
    width: 1240px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<nav>
    <div class='wrapper'>
        <ul class="container">
            <li>Images</li>
            <li>Albums</li>
            <li>Tags</li>
            <li class='space'></li>
            <li>Log In</li>
            <li>Sign Up</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use percent to make it responsive.
Or, add `max-width: 100%;` if you want to maintain `width: 1240px;`

```css
.container {
    display: flex;
}
.container>li {
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1em;
    color: white;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-color: black;
    list-style-type: none;
}
.space {
    flex: 1;
}
.wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<nav>
    <div class='wrapper'>
        <ul class="container">
            <li>Images</li>
            <li>Albums</li>
            <li>Tags</li>
            <li class='space'></li>
            <li>Log In</li>
            <li>Sign Up</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `width: 100%;` to `nav` and `wrapper`

```css
.container {
    display: flex;
}
.container>li {
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1em;
    color: white;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-color: black;
    list-style-type: none;
}
.space {
    flex: 1;
}
.wrapper {
    width: 1240px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
nav{    
width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<nav>
    <div class='wrapper'>
        <ul class="container">
            <li>Images</li>
            <li>Albums</li>
            <li>Tags</li>
            <li class='space'></li>
            <li>Log In</li>
            <li>Sign Up</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: taht what you mean??

Comment: I tried the code but now the elements are not in the middle of the page, the first 3 <li> elements are at the left side and the last 2 are at the right side.

Comment: use `padding: 0;` to `.container`